# unable to disable FlatButton

Tags: android, android-layout

I have Buttons that use the `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless` style with a custom color selector that changes the textColor according to the enabled state.

It generally works, but when the Button is initially disabled (in XML or in code), it won't. The Button will look clickable and is clickable. As soon as i add a small delay of just 100 Milliseconds, it works.

`clickable` on the other hand, works without any delays.

I've tried calling `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()` on the Button without success.

Anyone experienced anything like this?

Comment: Can you post a simple project with that behavior on github? What API version are you running on?

Comment: guess i might as well do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fooled myself! The presenter checks for an active connection and enabled the Button.

That also explains the 100ms workaround.

Gotta hate the feeling of wasting hours to your own stupidity.